# path.exists returns unexpected result after rmtree command

Tags: python, python-3.x

The goal is to:

1. create a folder if it doesn't exist
2. delete a folder with
   all items if it exists and then create a new empty folder

```
search_dir = path.join(...,..., 'My_Folder')

rmtree(search_dir , ignore_errors=True)

if not path.exists(search_dir):
    makedirs(search_dir)
```

That code works fine if the folder doesn't exist or folder has no files. 
But it doesn't create a new empty folder if it has some files.

Comment: you need to add condition where if the path exists then delete that path and create a new path

Answer (score 4):

You pass `ignore_errors=True` to `rmtree()`, so if any error occurs during the call (like the directory contains some file you don't have permissions on) you won't be warned - but the function will have failed nonetheless. Solution: dont ignore errors, handle them - either using a try/except block around the call or by passing an `onerror` callback to `rmtree` (cf the doc).